# How to write group by function for the location field in calendar module in Odoo v8?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I inherited the default search `view` of *Calendar* module and wanted to add a `group by` filter additional to that of existing `group by` filters.

```
Filter in xml - filter string="Locations" icon="terp-locked" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'location'}"
```

How can I get the records under a particular location ?

A little help anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<record id="customer_followup_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Search</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_res_partner_filter"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <group string="Group By" position="inside">
            <filter string="Follow-up Responsible" context="{'group_by':'payment_responsible_id'}"/>
        </group>

    </field>
</record>
```